# why is でのこと used?

Tags: words, meaning, particle-の, particle-で

I have two questions regarding the opening lines of a short story called 真夜中の王女(midnight princess)

> ある王国**でのこと**。
>   うつくしい王女が十五歳でなくなって、そのなきがらをおさめたひつぎが、教会にはこびこまれた。

1. Is the use of でのこと just to give the impression that something is happening or taking place.
2. Is the verb associated with object marker をおさめた 収める？And if so is なきがらをおさめたひつぎが a polite set phrase that means the burial casket. or is the literal meaning they want because it is a horror story therefore it would be something like corpse interned coffin.

so my interpretation is,
In a kingdom a 15 year old beautiful princess passed away and her corpse interned casket was carried to the church.

Comment: I think the ([棺]{ひつぎ}に)おさめる is written as **納**める http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/clj/471014/meaning/m0u/

Comment: Please ask one question per question, even if they're about the same text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, 王国のこと would just refer to "something about a certain kingdom". Adding で to get "王国でのこと" means "something that happened in a certain kingdom".

To give a similar example "バスでの旅行" means "a trip via a bus". Removing the で here would mean just "a trip of a bus".

So yes, your interpretation of this point is generally correct.

Since this looks like a fairy tale, if you were doing a proper translation you might use a more appropriate English phrase, like "Once upon a time in a kingdom".

For your second question, I think Choco's comment confirms the usage of the verb おさめる in question here.

I would translate this part more as "the coffin carrying the princess's body..."

Comment: So "の" is 格助词 in this case？