# その出会いはある日の職場の飲み会でのこと

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning and function of the word koto in this sentence?

> その出会いはある日の職場の飲み会でのこと

I’ve asked everywhere but I still haven’t received an explanation that not only made sense to me but also helped me understand when and how to use こと this way.

Comment: Possible dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32215/45489

Comment: I smell that we need more context, especially what comes after this phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Ending an extended phrase with a noun like this means the phrase modifies the noun. So, in means "thing" in English, therefore:

"It happened at a workplace drinking thing."

This is informal in English but is completely acceptable in Japanese.

Comment: So based on what I understand it has the meaning of event, so the focus is on the event that happened and everything before の is the setting of the event?
So is translating the sentence as
"(The event that happened during) that encounter that
day at the company drinking party" correct?
If so then (i made a phrase to see if I really understood)
does the phrase
「姉と彼氏の結婚前旅行でのこと悲 しました。」
mean: "what happened at /the event that happened
during my sister and her boyfriend trip before the
wedding made me sad"

Comment: @StefaniaOgun 「～でのこと悲しました」は変です。（「悲しました」という形はないです）

Comment: じゃ、「悲しかった」いいですか。